# FreeRADIUS - Can a username be altered?

Tags: proxy, freeradius

Is there a way to alter a username before it before FreeRADIUS proxy it?

Example, you have the username "abcuser@abc.com" coming to the FreeRADIUS server, the FreeRADIUS server changes the username to "123user@abc.com" and proxy it to the defined RADIUS server.

Answer (score 0):

Sure.  Change the username using the policy language in the authorize section

```
authorize {
    # This is a policy which ships with the server
    # It breaks the incoming username into
    # - Stripped-User-Name
    # - Stripped-User-Domain
    split_username_nai
    if (&Stripped-User-Domain) {
        update request {
            User-Name := "123user@%{Stripped-User-Domain}"
        }
    }
}
```